# Infinite loop redirects when I do login with saml

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

after I've readed all the theads with possible solutions, no one has worked for me.

I have installed the simplesamlphp library with composer and I have configured the vhost of this application in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.myapp.domain.org
    Redirect permanent / https://local.myapp.domain.org/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\local.myapp.domain.org"
    ServerName local.myapp.domain.org
    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    # URL del backend web
    SetEnv BACKEND_URL https://local.myapp.domain.org/
    SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR "C:\xampp\htdocs\local.myapp.domain.org\vendor\simplesamlphp\simplesamlphp\config"
    Alias /simplesamlphp C:\xampp\htdocs\local.myapp.domain.org\vendor\simplesamlphp\simplesamlphp\www
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\local.myapp.domain.org\vendor\simplesamlphp\simplesamlphp\www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Domain local.myapp.domain.org is configured as a hosts in my computer.

I've downloaded the metadata of my Idp (SAP successfactors), I've converted with the tool of simplesamlphp and I've pasted the resultant array in the file saml20-idp-remote.php.

Later, I have asked the administrator of my Idp to record my metadata in his Idp, obtained from here

[ldp obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XAnP.png)

When I test the authentication source from simplesamlphp,It asks me for the credentials in the login screen of the Idp and it works perfect.

[auth test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4WSz.png)

Then, I've implemented a simple login test in my app like this.

```
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);
```

Then when I execute that code, I am redirected to the login screen of my Idp, asking for my credentials, I enter them, and it constantly loops on the screen of my Idp saml.

[login loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5DJc.png)

My config.php of simplesamlphp

```
<?php

$config = [

    'baseurlpath' => 'simplesamlphp/',
    'certdir' => 'cert/',
    'loggingdir' => 'log/',
    'datadir' => 'data/',
    'tempdir' => '/tmp/simplesaml',
    'technicalcontact_name' => 'Administrator',
    'technicalcontact_email' => 'na@example.org',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
    'secretsalt' => 'f343434535',
    'auth.adminpassword' => '123',
    'admin.protectindexpage' => false,
    'admin.protectmetadata' => false,
    'admin.checkforupdates' => true,
    'trusted.url.domains' => [],
    'trusted.url.regex' => false,
    'enable.http_post' => false,
    'assertion.allowed_clock_skew' => 180,
    'debug' => [
        'saml' => false,
        'backtraces' => true,
        'validatexml' => false,
    ],
    'showerrors' => true,
    'errorreporting' => true,
    'logging.level' => SimpleSAML\Logger::NOTICE,
    'logging.handler' => 'syslog',
    'logging.facility' => defined('LOG_LOCAL5') ? constant('LOG_LOCAL5') : LOG_USER,
    'logging.processname' => 'simplesamlphp',
    'logging.logfile' => 'simplesamlphp.log',
    'statistics.out' => [
    ],
    'proxy' => null,

    'database.dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saml',

    
    'database.username' => 'simplesamlphp',
    'database.password' => 'secret',
    'database.options' => [],

    'database.prefix' => '',

    
    'database.driver_options' => [],

    'database.persistent' => false,

    'database.slaves' => [
        
    ],


    'enable.saml20-idp' => false,
    'enable.shib13-idp' => false,
    'enable.adfs-idp' => false,
    'shib13.signresponse' => true,
     'module.enable' => [
         'exampleauth' => false,
         'core' => true,
         'saml' => true
     ],
    'session.duration' => 8 * (60 * 60), // 8 hours.
    'session.datastore.timeout' => (4 * 60 * 60), // 4 hours
    'session.state.timeout' => (60 * 60), // 1 hour
    'session.cookie.name' => 'SimpleSAMLSessionID',
    'session.cookie.lifetime' => 0,
    'session.cookie.path' => '/',
    'session.cookie.domain' => null,
    'session.cookie.secure' => true,
    'session.cookie.samesite' => \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::canSetSameSiteNone() ? 'None' : null,
    'session.phpsession.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAML',
    'session.phpsession.savepath' => null,
    'session.phpsession.httponly' => true,
    'session.authtoken.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAMLAuthToken',
    'session.rememberme.enable' => false,
    'session.rememberme.checked' => false,
    'session.rememberme.lifetime' => (14 * 86400),
    'memcache_store.servers' => [
        [
            ['hostname' => 'localhost'],
        ],
    ],
    'memcache_store.prefix' => '',
    'memcache_store.expires' => 36 * (60 * 60), // 36 hours.
    'language' => [
        'priorities' => [
            'no' => ['nb', 'nn', 'en', 'se'],
            'nb' => ['no', 'nn', 'en', 'se'],
            'nn' => ['no', 'nb', 'en', 'se'],
            'se' => ['nb', 'no', 'nn', 'en'],
            'nr' => ['zu', 'en'],
            'nd' => ['zu', 'en'],
            'tw' => ['st', 'en'],
            'nso' => ['st', 'en'],
        ],
    ],
    'language.available' => [
        'en', 'no', 'nn', 'se', 'da', 'de', 'sv', 'fi', 'es', 'ca', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'lb',
        'cs', 'sl', 'lt', 'hr', 'hu', 'pl', 'pt', 'pt-br', 'tr', 'ja', 'zh', 'zh-tw', 'ru',
        'et', 'he', 'id', 'sr', 'lv', 'ro', 'eu', 'el', 'af', 'zu', 'xh', 'st',
    ],
    'language.rtl' => ['ar', 'dv', 'fa', 'ur', 'he'],
    'language.default' => 'en',
    'language.parameter.name' => 'language',
    'language.parameter.setcookie' => true,
    'language.cookie.name' => 'language',
    'language.cookie.domain' => null,
    'language.cookie.path' => '/',
    'language.cookie.secure' => true,
    'language.cookie.httponly' => false,
    'language.cookie.lifetime' => (60 * 60 * 24 * 900),
    'language.cookie.samesite' => \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::canSetSameSiteNone() ? 'None' : null,
    'attributes.extradictionary' => null,
    'theme.use' => 'default',
    'template.auto_reload' => false,
    'production' => true,
    'assets' => [
        'caching' => [
            'max_age' => 86400,
            'etag' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'idpdisco.enableremember' => true,
    'idpdisco.rememberchecked' => true,
    'idpdisco.validate' => true,
    'idpdisco.extDiscoveryStorage' => null,
    'idpdisco.layout' => 'dropdown',
    'authproc.idp' => [
        30 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

        45 => [
            'class'         => 'core:StatisticsWithAttribute',
            'attributename' => 'realm',
            'type'          => 'saml20-idp-SSO',
        ],
        50 => 'core:AttributeLimit',
        99 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',
    ],

    'authproc.sp' => [
        90 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',
    ],
    'metadatadir' => 'metadata',
    'metadata.sources' => [
        ['type' => 'flatfile'],
    ],
    'metadata.sign.enable' => false,
    'metadata.sign.privatekey' => null,
    'metadata.sign.privatekey_pass' => null,
    'metadata.sign.certificate' => null,
    'store.type'                    => 'phpsession',
    'store.sql.dsn'                 => 'sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedatabase.sq3',
    'store.sql.username' => null,
    'store.sql.password' => null,
    'store.sql.prefix' => 'SimpleSAMLphp',
    'store.redis.host' => 'localhost',
    'store.redis.port' => 6379,
    'store.redis.prefix' => 'SimpleSAMLphp',
];
```

On the simpleamlphp test screen it works fine, but when I try to integrate it into a controller of my application with codeigniter, it doesn't work, it starts a redirect loop.

I've been reading multiple possible solutions, it seems like it is a cookie setting problem in simplesaml, but I'm not sure.

**Update:** I've tried to change the store type from phpsession to sql, as explained here https://koas.dev/simplesamlphp-como-resolver-el-error-could-not-load-state-specified-by-inresponseto-nostate-processing-response-as-unsolicited/ and it has worked perfect, but with php session still no working.

Comment: Could you check the log for your applications simpleSAML instance when the loop happends?

Comment: @StefanRasmusson In each loop, prints this message on the log file simplesamlphp.log

Jan 14 08:41:17 simplesamlphp WARNING [a53d8d7c7f] Could not load state specified by InResponseTo: NOSTATE Processing response as unsolicited.

Comment: Ok, nothing else? Im expecting to see some error or warning after that make the application try to authenticate again.  Could you also pull out one SAML authn message and SAML response message XML from your browser. You can for example use this on Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-devtools-extension/jndllhgbinhiiddokbeoeepbppdnhhio?hl=en-US

Comment: Have you read this article? https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-nostate It seems to have many suggestions on what can be wrong